# Are Sinks more important than Sources in security?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am trying to grasp my head around what should be prioritized for security during programming. Let's take the relationship of MySQL, and PHP.

To prevent nasties from doing Cross Site Scripting, SQL Injection, etc; From bunch of articles I've read, it seems like sanitizing/cleaning the source (User Input Data, etc) is enough to tackle most attacks. However in contrast, in Static source scanner app communities, Sinks seem to be more focused rather than Sources. (The data pool / databases / file being written to). Why is that?

I guess in the perfect world a lot of the attacks if not most can be handled with source handling right? With the correct sanitization methods, a lot of the attacks can be stopped...

How would one even remediate security problems in Sinks not sources??

Comment: There's a difference between preventing an SQL injection attack, which  is designed to break the database service and an attack that will grant someone access to your data. SQL injection is easily prevented. The other one - is not. That's where doomsday scenarios come into play - what if someone got access to my server? How do I prevent that person from (easily) obtaining my data. That's where various security methods play a huge role. Your question is a bit ambiguous I must admit, please expand it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

> With the correct sanitization methods, a lot of the attacks can be stopped...

You can only stop attacks at the source if you have a complete list of all possible sinks, so you can remove characters that might be ‘special’ in *any* of those formats. This is impractical because almost all punctuation is ‘special’ in some context, and usually people do need to be able to use punctuation in most applications. And even then, filtering punctuation wouldn't protect you against an unquoted SQL injection (the `OR 1` attack).

Input validation is at best a defence-in-depth measure and not sufficient in itself against injection attacks. (It of course has other benefits than security though.)

> How would one even remediate security problems in Sinks not sources?

1. the correct form of output escaping for the context;
2. where there is no standard form of escaping, filtering of out-of-band characters or ad hoc escaping (eg there is no standard way to include `;` in a cookie value, but some apps decide to treat cookies as being URL-encoded);
3. best of all and especially where contexts are nested because that's really hard to get right—use interfaces that abstract away the need for escaping, such as parameterised SQL queries, and templating languages that automatically escape.

I want the word “sanitization” to go away forever. [rant](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php)

Comment: Wow awesome... thanks for the reply. So there needs to be both source and sink based security measures to make things "secure"; not just stopping at the source or trying to at least... (Did I get the point?) So I have a curveball throw at you... if you have a lost source (there is data coming in, but you don't know exactly where from) and it's reported in the security application.. how would you try to fix that problem? What about lost sinks? (..is one more important than the other?). Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the application and what is it complaining about? Security scanners by necessity generate many false positives; if you understand what a source is and you know it's safe then you can happily ignore the finding. I've not heard the term “lost”—is this referring to sources/sinks that leads into other components the scanner doesn't know how to scan? Again you will need understanding of what those components are doing to decide whether they're safe or not; if there are significant parts of the application that aren't being covered it may be time to look at a different scanner that can.

Comment: In general sink-side processing (escaping et al) is necessary *and* sufficient to address the ‘injection’ class of bugs; source-side processing (input validation) isn't, but it can have a mitigating effect on sink-side processing failures and you're going to want it anyway for enforcing business rules. The class of vulnerabilities caught by sink/source taint tracking is a bit wider than just injection: it also detects sins of design where you deliberately do something stupid like pass a user command directly to the shell, for which no amount of escaping or filtering would help you!

Comment: (And of course there are many, many other class of app-specific logical errors that taint tracking cannot hope to detect...)

Comment: Lost or Missing Sink sorry seems to be the term. It's for a lot of the scanning applications I believe; HP's, IBM and the open source RIPS. Missing Sink is a method that the app knows that it exists but it does not know specifically what method... (I guess from what i've learned, you wouldn't know what kind of action to take if there is a missing sink but you know the sources)